# Getting mouse down event on superview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, subview, superview, mousedown

I have an `NSScrollView` and its document view is an `NSView` subview titled MasterPage. On MasterPage I have a bunch (depending on user input) of subviews (from a class called Page).They are laid out in a grid format. I'm trying to capture the `NSPoint` of the mouse click on MasterPage. It works where there are no subviews but if the point clicked is within the area of a subview then the superview does not register it. Is there a way to do this? I hope that makes sense.

The red area registers a mouse click in the superview's .m file. The four subviews do not.

[image: The red area registers a mouse click in the superview's .m file. The four subviews do not.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MasterPage` class, you could override `NSView's` [`-hitTest:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/hitTest:) method and have it return `self` rather than one of the `Page` subviews. See [Event Handling Guide: The Path of Mouse and Tablet Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW21).

In this example project, http://www.markdouma.com/developer/SubviewSuperview.zip, you can watch the logging calls to see what `NSView` receives the events. If you hold down the Alt/Option key and click, the white view will override `-hitTest:` and return itself, preventing the gray views from receiving the event.

[image]